# IDEA Play 2.4 junit test without full sbt build

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, playframework, sbt

I want to run JUnit tests for my Play 2.4 application within Intellij IDEA 14.1.4 to leverage full JUnit integration.

The tests are executed fine when I create a new JUnit run configuration. However on every test run a full SBT build is executed delaying the tests for around 30 seconds. 
[image: Example JUnit run configuration]

If I remove `Make` form the pre-launch steps in the JUnit run configuration the tests are executed directly without a full sbt build but then any code changes in test and application code are not picked up by IDEA. Even when the play is running with auto-compile on file changes IDEA doesn't pick them up for the tests.

## Edit 07/09/2015

I've also exchanged `Make` with an `SBT Action test:compile` which only opens up a SBT console loading the project and stops with a prompt. It's not executing the action test:compile and therefore not starting the test at all.

What do I have to change in run configuration and/or project settings to get a fast and seamless JUnit integration for Play projects in IDEA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer myself when digging through [issue tickets of idea-sbt-plugin](https://github.com/orfjackal/idea-sbt-plugin/issues/86).

Exchanging Pre launch Step `Make` with `SBT Action test:compile` was the right way to go. However the SBT Plugin expects the default sbt shellPromt `>`. Play projects however define their own custom promt as `[projectname] $`.

I had to add the following line to `build.sbt` to get the SBT action to work.

```
    shellPrompt := (_ => "> ")
```

Comment: Can you explain how to create a SBT Action and use it in pre launch step?

Comment: Prerequesite: SBT Plugin installed.
Open your Run/Debug configuration for your test. You might want to edit the template so that every test uses this configuration. Select 'Make', Click '-' in section 'Before launch'. Click '+' to add a new Before step. Select SBT. Enter 'test:compile' as action (not available in the drop down values, enter it manually)